# xlwings import error in python 2.7: Can't import name Workbook

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwings

(I know there is an original question regarding this issue but it differs a bit by having command run in home directory. Also no specific solution is mentioned)

I am using Anaconda2  python 2.7 (64bit) distribution. I have installed xlwings (version 0.9.3) on it using

```
pip install xlwings
```

Now I am trying to run a very basic command (in Ipython qtconsole):

```
from xlwings import Workbook
```

to which I get error as:

```
cannot import name workbook
```

I tried the same with a python script saved in my home directory which gave same error. However following command runs fine:

```
from xlwings import Range, Chart, __version__
```

Can anyone point out, what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `where pip.exe`

Comment: `where pip.exe` gives output `\Appdata\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts\pip.exe`

Comment: is Office 32-bit installed on your system?

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your post? Not just the last little bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Workbook` has been renamed into `Book` with the 0.9 release, see the [migration guide](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/migrate_to_0.9.html#cheat-sheet), follow the [quickstart](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) or simply look at the [API](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html).